# How to set the code page of a Delphi 2006 executable

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006, codepages

We're programming in Delphi 2006, using Multilizer 5.1 to translate the program. Now we've to added Polish as a new language in Multilizer. But when we open our executable, Multlizer says "Polish is not supported by the codepage".

If we adjust our regional settings to Polish, whenever we open the executable, the regional settings flip back to the original setting, which is Dutch. Maybe we should set the CodePage setting in our Project Options, but the dropdown list does not give us any options.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out we only had to set the Language for non-Unicode programs in the Regional and Language Options in Control Panel. The bad news is that the French version is now having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your application to support all possible language regardless of the Regional and Language Options on the user's computer, you'll need to migrate your application to Delphi 2009 or later.  Starting with Delphi 2009, Delphi produces Unicode applications.  It'll likely take some effort to fix any code that assumes that `SizeOf(Char) = 1`.  But that one-time job should be much less effort than constantly having to deal with code page issues in your Delphi 2006 application.